# google checkout - how can i extract info from array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, google-checkout

I've recently been having issues with google checkout - i believe the customer ip address is no longer being returned in the response.

However, i'm not sure how to view all parts of the array. How can i capture the array in a string, which i can then email to myself to investgate all values being passed back.

it used to be returned in:
$data[$root]['risk-information']['ip-address']['VALUE']

I've tried to var_dump $data and $root but $root gave blank email:

```
$to = "*********";
    $from = "*******";
    $subject = "debugging GC";

    $messagecont = var_dump($data);

    $headers  = "From: ".$from."\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n"; 

    $success = mail($to, $subject, $messagecont, $headers);
```

Comment: have you tried viewing what is in the array with var_dump($data); ? It is super helpful to see what you have and the structure of the array to the piece you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
$messagecont = serialize($data);
```

This will send back the whole array in a format that you can later just [unserialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)